# Structs and malloc code getting weird outputs

Tags: c, struct, malloc, switch-statement

Its me again and making progress... I want to say thanks to everyone who commented on my last question, it was very helpful.  I got this to compile so far but having some weird bugs that I can't iron out.

```
void addRecord(){//carries users input data

numRecs++;//increments numRecs by 1 

struct record library; //this will hold info for user input

printf ("Please enter your first name:\n");
fgets(library.fName, sizeof(library.fName), stdin);
printf ("Please enter your last name:\n");
fgets(library.lName, sizeof(library.lName), stdin);
printf ("Please enter your hometown:\n");
fgets(library.hometown, sizeof(library.hometown), stdin);


printf("You entered %s for your first name.\n", library.fName);
printf("You entered %s for your last name.\n", library.lName);
printf("You entered %s for your hometown.\n", library.hometown);


struct record *myNewRecord;//creates a new struct pointer to store   all the old data and new data


myNewRecord = malloc(numRecs * sizeof(struct record));      //allocates space to fit all old data plus the new struct data
if (myNewRecord == NULL)
{
fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory\n");
}

*myNewRecord = library;

fprintf(stderr, "You made it here!!\n");
```

These are the results I get from the terminal.. It looks like the syntax is all correct in the source code but  the issue is it skips the first name fgets for some reason.  Also, when it prints out it executes a return somehow. Can you guys see whats going on??? P.S. It doesn't do this when I eliminate the switch case and only have addrecord() in the main.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gcc lab222.c -o lab222
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./lab222

Please select from the following:
 1. Print all records.
 2. Print number of records.
 3. Print size of database.
 4. Add record.
 5. Delete record.
 6. Print number of accesses to database.
 7. Exit.
Enter a number 1-7:4
Please enter your first name:
Please enter your last name:
Don
Please enter your hometown:
Mega
You entered 
 for your first name.
You entered Don
 for your last name.
You entered Mega
 for your hometown.
You made it here!!
```

Comment: I was just wondering, it the reason I have the second part of my sentence on another line because I allocated 50 bytes for space and its uses all of it?

Comment: You're calling `scanf()` twice when you ask for the selection from the menu. You also need to do something to read the newline after the selection, otherwise it will be treated as the first input in `addRecord()`.

Comment: Nix the 3 `scanf()`,  Replace with `while ((scanf("%d", &sel) != 1) ||(sel < 1) || (sel > 7)) {`

Comment: I thought I needed those three scanf().  The first one lets the user choose which option they want int the switch statement. The second accounts for all the number that don't fall in the range of 1-7. Lastly, the third is a fail safe for the dreaded char entry, which creates an indefinite loop.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, use fgets() and then sscanf()

Comment: Thanks Chux and Barmar!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations,

- Save reallocating the array and copying the previous values for every record
- allocate an array of pointers to new records, and fill that array as you add records
- you can reallocate that pointer array much cheaper than the data records
- move you menu display and menu choice determination to separate functions
- you will probably add a linked list (head, mover?), so the pointer array is close
- use fgets to read input, it is less twitchy than scanf
- you can still use sscanf to extract your menu choice (that fixed the problem)

Here is the revised record storage,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> //needed for malloc, free
#include<string.h> // needed for the memcpy
#define MAX 100

struct record
{
    char fName[MAX];
    char lName[MAX];
    char hometown[MAX];
};             //structure template/declaration
struct record* records[500]; //allow room for 500 (for now)
int numRecords=0;  //stores number of records, used for several tasks

//prototypes
int addRecord();
```

here are functions to display menu and read input (view)

```
//********MENU***********
int menushow(FILE* fh)
{
    printf("\nPlease select from the following:\n");
    printf(" 1. Print all records.\n");
    printf(" 2. Print number of records.\n");
    printf(" 3. Print size of database.\n");
    printf(" 4. Add record.\n");
    printf(" 5. Delete record.\n");
    printf(" 6. Print number of accesses to database.\n");
    printf(" 7. Exit.\n");
    printf("Enter a number 1-7:");
    return 0;
}
int menudo(char* line)
{
    int sel;
    int choice;
    if( sscanf(line,"%d",&sel) < 1 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, not a valid input. Must be a number from 1 to 7.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    switch(choice = atoi(line))
    {

    case 1:

        break;

    case 2:

        break;

    case 3:

        break;

    case 4:
        if( addRecord() < 0 )    //This creates a new record based of input into struct library.
            fprintf(stderr,"addRecord failure\n");
        break;
    case 5:

        break;

    case 6:

        break;

    case 7:
        exit(0);
        break;

    default:
        printf("\nError, not valid input. Please enter a  number from 1 to 7.\n\n");
        break;
    }
    return choice;
}
```

Here is main with the menu processing extracted to functions,

```
#define EXITCHOICE 7
int main(void)
{
    char line[MAX+1];
    int action=0;
    while (action<EXITCHOICE)
    {
        menushow(stdout);
        if( !fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin) ) { break; }
        //printf("entered: %s\n",line);
        if( (action=menudo(line)) < 0 ) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the simpler addrecord,

```
//** Beginning of addRecord**
//returns -1 on failure
int
addRecord()
{//carries users input data
    struct record library; //this will hold info for user input
    struct record *myNewRecord; //creates a new struct pointer to store   all the old data and new data

    printf ("Please enter your first name:\n");
    if(!fgets(library.fName, sizeof(library.fName), stdin)) return -1;
    printf ("Please enter your last name:\n");
    if(!fgets(library.lName, sizeof(library.lName), stdin)) return -1;
    printf ("Please enter your hometown:\n");
    if(!fgets(library.hometown, sizeof(library.hometown), stdin)) return -1;

    printf("You entered %s for your first name.\n", library.fName);
    printf("You entered %s for your last name.\n", library.lName);
    printf("You entered %s for your hometown.\n", library.hometown);

    records[numRecords] = (struct record*)malloc(sizeof(struct record));      //allocates space to fit all old data plus the new struct data
    if (records[numRecords] == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"error: Out of memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
    memcpy(records[numRecords],&library,sizeof(struct record));
    numRecords++;//increments numRecords by 1 
    fprintf(stderr, "[%d] records!!\n",numRecords);
    return(numRecords);
}
```

Comment: WOW Chuck!!! You're are life saver... My teacher wasn't help me very much but this all makes sense. THanks SOOOO MUCH!!

Comment: Learning to program can be hard.  I've been doing this for awhile.  And I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
scanf("%d",&sel);
if (scanf("%d", &sel) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, not a valid input. Must be a number from 1 to 7.\n");
    scanf("%s", &c);
    continue;
}
```

to:

```
char reponse[MAX];
fgets(response, sizeof response, stdin);
int result = sscanf(response, "%d", &sel);
if (result != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, not a valid input. Must be a number from 1 to 7.\n");
    continue;
}
```

Using `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()` solves the problem of not reading the newline when you use `scanf()` by itself. You were also calling `scanf()` again in the `if`, so it was reading the input twice.

Comment: I had to declare result as an int at the beginning of main and changed stding to stdin.  Besides that WORKED GREAT... Thanks so much guys.